# Wiremock ignores certificates stored in a custom keystore

Tags: keystore, wiremock, testcontainers

I'm starting docker containers using Testcontainers lib. 
I have a main container which receives requests and then sends to wiremock. They are HTTPS requests and in order to handle those I created SA certificates, put it to 'resources' and supplied to wiremock container via volume:

```
private static GenericContainer buildWiremockContainer() {

    final String mappingsLocalDir = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(".").getPath(), "wiremock").toString();
    final String mappingsContainerDir = "/home/wiremock";

    final String keystoreLocalDir = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(".").getPath(), "keystore").toString();
    final String keystoreContainerDir = "/tmp/keystore";

    return new GenericContainer(WIREMOCK_IMAGE)
            .withFileSystemBind(
                    mappingsLocalDir,
                    mappingsContainerDir,
                    BindMode.READ_ONLY)
            .withFileSystemBind(
                    keystoreLocalDir,
                    keystoreContainerDir,
                    BindMode.READ_ONLY)
            .withCommand("--https-port 8443 --https-keystore /tmp/identity_certificate.jks --verbose")
            .withNetwork(Network.SHARED);
}
```

After wiremock container has started I see the following:

```
port:                         8080
https-port:                   8443
https-keystore:               /tmp/keystore/identity_cert.jks
```

AND inside the container:

```
root@f0b72dca7651:/tmp/keystore# pwd && ls -lah
/tmp/keystore
total 20K
drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000 4.0K Oct 29 07:53 .
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4.0K Oct 29 07:53 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 4.5K Oct 29 07:53 identity_cert.jks
```

Though, whenever I send HTTPS requests I always get message like

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-29T07:57:22.305+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching demo.docusign.net found",
    "path": "/v1/transferToCustodian"
}
```

despite my keystore contains certificates with specified CN:

```
root@f0b72dca7651:/tmp/keystore#  keytool -list -v -keystore identity_cert.jks -storepass password | grep demo.docusign
Owner: CN=demo.docusign.net, OU=demo.docusign.net, O=demo.docusign.net, L=demo.docusign.net, ST=demo.docusign.net, C=UA
Issuer: CN=demo.docusign.net, OU=demo.docusign.net, O=demo.docusign.net, L=demo.docusign.net, ST=demo.docusign.net, C=UA
```

Comment: The issue is that one wiremock container can contain keystore with one unique CN. The solution was to start a new wiremock container for each unique keystore which contains unique CN.